# Laravel Echo is not listening while using Web Socket

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vue.js, websocket

I am making chat using web socket listening port, Now I install websocket and pusher following this video link on you tube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_4UubWE9NQ&t=712s)

But after following all step started websocket serve and its running successfully but when calling php artisan serve and running URL getting error on console.

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/popper.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404,
> net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Web socket is not listening the port, here is my code of event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class WebsocketDemoEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $somedata;
    
    public function __construct($somedata)
    {
        $this->somedata = $somedata;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('DemoChannel');
    }
}
```

This is web route where calling event.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    broadcast(new WebsocketDemoEvent('some data'));
    return view('welcome');
});
```

This is my bootstrap.js code

```
window._ = require('lodash');
import Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js';

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = Popper;
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
});


 window.Echo.channel('DemoChannel').listen('WebsocketDemoEvent', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
 });
```

welcome page code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app" class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Documentation</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is package JSON

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.2",
        "pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
        "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.3.5"
    }
```

I tried all the solution from internet and stack over flow but none is able to solve this , please help to solve this issue, Thank you in advance , Picture where I am not getting demo channel response.
[image]

And when tried to send message from Web Socket channel getting response
[image]
this is the console of web socket page console error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) /admin/websocket/api/anyID/statistics:1 Failed to load
> resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> /admin/websocket/event:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
> with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Please help me with it, I am very new with web Socket.

Comment: check your network tab `ws` section websocket is connected or not

Comment: could you explain , how to check it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuTI4.png check like this

Comment: 3 step as on picture showing there is not any request showing blank space

Comment: it's means your not listing  for any channel in java script

Comment: please can you explain how to list for channel , I did everything as showed in tutorial and his socket is running and showing data on channel and when i am doing this on websocket  trying to call websocket event it is showing this error jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/admin/websocket/event 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you put `Echo.channel('DemoChannel').listen('WebsocketDemoEvent',` this in on load function

Comment: on load function it is still not working, may be when i am opening welcome page at least it should show console message but it showing this error "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/popper.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"

Comment: no this is coming from vue devtool not in your application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227955/discussion-between-vikash-and-kamlesh-paul).

Comment: then why app.js is not listening to my channel sir

Comment: `Echo.channel('DemoChannel')` this is the code which is responsible to listen  were did you put this?

Comment: in bootstrap.js file and this boostrap is import in app.js and now i am scripting app.js in my welcome page {require('./bootstrap');} , {<script src="js/app.js"></script> }

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution for this problem

1. Check if pusher is install if not then  Install the pusher-js
2. After run `npm run watch` on terminal
3. Run `admin/websocket` on same channel like http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/websocket and console where you are calling the route in which websocket broadcoast calling like http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

Now when I am sending data from channel it is receiving it is receiving on welcome route console.